# Mesh Combiner in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, mesh

Hello I am using this guy's script https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wYAlky1aZn4
to combine meshes because the game is "lagging" or whatever it's called when the when it doesn't run smooth. I have 34*124 cubes with two different meshes and all works perfect if I put the script on a object with 34*20  childern (the same cubes that I mentioned before) but if I put it on the object that has 32*124 children it turnes them into something that looks like it has 34*20 cubes.

Basically it if I put the script on something that has more childern it turns it into something smaller.

This is the code from the video:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CombineMeshes : MonoBehaviour {
    public void Combine(){
        Quaternion oldRot = transform.rotation;
        Vector3 oldPos = transform.position;

        transform.rotation = Quaternion.identity;
        transform.position = Vector3.zero;

        MeshFilter[] filters = GetComponentsInChildren<MeshFilter> ();

        Mesh finalMesh = new Mesh ();

        CombineInstance[] combiners = new CombineInstance[filters.Length];

        for (int a = 0; a < filters.Length; a++) {
            if (filters [a].transform == transform) {
                continue;
            }

            combiners [a].subMeshIndex = 0;
            combiners [a].mesh = filters [a].sharedMesh;
            combiners [a].transform = filters [a].transform.localToWorldMatrix;
        }

        finalMesh.CombineMeshes (combiners);

        GetComponent<MeshFilter> ().sharedMesh = finalMesh;

        transform.rotation = oldRot;
        transform.position = oldPos;
        for (int a= 0; a < transform.childCount; a++) {
            transform.GetChild (a).gameObject.SetActive (false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not quite sure what the problem is because your sentence after "I have 34*124 cube" is a bit broken but one guess might be did you consider vertex limit (65,534) of unity. If your combined mesh would have more than the limit you need to have another mesh or you need to use `UInt32` as `Mesh.IndexFormat`. Are those cubes Unity pirimitive cubes or something else? How many vertices do those cubes have?

Comment: no these cubes are from the asset's store. I meant to say that I created a ground of those cubes and its 34 cubes wide and 124 cubes long. I just check every cubes has 96 vertices ( I did Debu.Log(mesh.vertices.Length;)

Comment: Finaly it worked!! I added this

finalMesh.indexFormat = UnityEngine.Rendering.IndexFormat.UInt32;

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is exactly the vertex limit problem you are having. With your set up 1 mesh can have only `34*20*96 = 65.280` vertices. After that you need another mesh. `124*34*96` makes `404,736` and is over the limit. Therefore, you need to change format of your mesh to `UInt32`. If the lag continues I can try to help further.