# Unity: cannot combine mesh that does not allow access: Cube

Tags: unity-game-engine

When I call `CombineMeshes()` I get 431 times the error:

```
Cannot combine mesh that does not allow access: Cube
UnityEngine.Mesh:CombineMeshes(CombineInstance[])
```

I've already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53835715/mesh-combiner-in-unity) and this.
I'm using Unity `2019.1.0f2` - hence if I want to use Blender, I'm forced to use Blender `2.80beta`.

I've made a very simple cube (it can't be simpler actually) and I've exported this into Unity as a `fbx` file:

[image: blender simple cube]

I've called it '`Wall`' like this:

[image: wall blender object]

From this I've made a prefab. Then I've made an empty object, created a script to generate the walls. It instanciates the prefabs to make walls, and this gives:

[image: wall generated]

But those prefab are simple cubes like this:

[image: wireframe view]

So I'd like to merge them. Unity has something ready for this: [`CombineMeshes()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh.CombineMeshes.html) .

I've tried to adapt the code in the link [`CombineMeshes()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh.CombineMeshes.html), so here's my full script which is very simple: it instanciates + tries to merge everything at the end:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

public class CoinGenerator : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject wallPrefab;
    public float gridSize = 40f;
    public float topPrefab = 60f;

    private void Start()
    {
        string[] ok = {
            "+------------+ +------------+",
            "|............| |............|",
            "|.+--+.+---+.| |.+---+.+--+.|",
            "|.|  |.|   |.| |.|   |.|  |.|",
            "|.+--+.+---+.+-+.+---+.+--+.|",
            "|............. .............|",
            "|.+--+.++.+-------+.++.+--+.|",
            "|.+--+.||.+--+ +--+.||.+--+.|",
            "|......||....| |....||......|",
            "+----+.|+--+.| |.+--+|.+----+",
            "     |.|+--+.+-+.+--+|.|     ",
            "     |.||..... .....||.|     ",
            "     |.||.+--- ---+.||.|     ",
            "-----+.++.|       |.++.+-----",
            "..........|       |..........",
            "-----+.++.|       |.++.+-----",
            "     |.||.+-------+.||.|     ",
            "     |.||...........||.|     ",
            "     |.||.+-------+.||.|     ",
            "+----+.++.+--+ +--+.++.+----+",
            "|............| |............|",
            "|.+--+.+---+.| |.+---+.+--+.|",
            "|.+-++.+---+.+-+.+---+.++-+.|",
            "|...||........ ........||...|",
            "+-+.||.++.+-------+.++.||.+-+",
            "+-+.++.||.+--+ +--+.||.++.+-+",
            "+......||....| |....||......+",
            "+.+----++--+.| |.+--++----+.+",
            "+.+--------+.+-+.+--------+.+",
            "+...........................+",
            "+---------------------------+"
        };
        MeshFilter[] meshFilters = {};
        for (int z = -14; z <= 16; z++) {
            for (int x = -14; x <= 14; x++) {
                char c = ok[30 - (z + 14)][x + 14];
                GameObject cp = null;
                if (c == '+' || c == '-' || c == '|') {
                    cp = Instantiate(wallPrefab, null, true);
                    MeshFilter[] m = cp.GetComponentsInChildren<MeshFilter>();
                    meshFilters = meshFilters.Concat(m).ToArray();
                }
                if (cp == null) {
                    continue;
                }
                cp.transform.position = new Vector3(
                    x * gridSize, topPrefab, z * gridSize
                );
            }
        }
        CombineInstance[] combine = new CombineInstance[meshFilters.Length];
        int i = 0;
        while (i < meshFilters.Length) {
            combine[i].mesh = meshFilters[i].sharedMesh;
            combine[i].transform = meshFilters[i].transform.localToWorldMatrix;
            // hide the objects, they will be merges into one:
            //meshFilters[i].gameObject.SetActive(false); 
            i++;
        }
        transform.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh = new Mesh();
        transform.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh.CombineMeshes(combine);
    }
}
```

When I call `CombineMeshes()` I get 431 times the error:

```
Cannot combine mesh that does not allow access: Cube
UnityEngine.Mesh:CombineMeshes(CombineInstance[])
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect that the Cube model you have imported from blender does not have the `Read/Write Enabled` flag set to true.

Go into the [Model Tab](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/FBXImporter-Model.html) for your imported model and make sure that `Read/Write Enabled` is set to true and apply your changes.

If this flag is already set then the only other thing I can think of is that there might be a call to `UploadMeshData()` somewhere in your code (or perhaps in a package you have imported?). `UploadMeshData()` takes a boolean as a parameter, and if it's true, will set the mesh to be no longer readable by scripts.

Comment: Your first solution was the right one. Is there a way to count the number of vertices to know if they are merged?

Comment: Well in my loop if I count the number of vertices it gives me 11736 and after the loop + the `CombineMeshes()` call, the current object gives me 11736 too. No actual merge or optimisation.

Comment: I have not personally experimented with combining meshes so I cannot give an answer for that with any certainty. However, since your meshes are simply cubes, I would be surprised if the vertex count would go down (since the combined mesh will still have all of the original vertices). If anything, I would expect the triangle indices of the mesh to be smaller since there ought to be fewer faces should the `CombineMeshes()` have worked correctly. Hope that helps.

Comment: My objective is to have any type of object (rounded cubes actually). But as far as I've seen, welding vertices is much more complex than is seems at first sight. However, from my experience, I know that I'll probably get light artefacts if they are not merged...

Comment: I suspect (though I might be wrong) that if you test this with shapes other than cubes that you will indeed see fewer vertices in the combined mesh. I cannot test this at the moment, can you?

Comment: I know this is an older post, but I was wondering if there has been any development on this. Any optimizations or pitfalls with going this route?