# How to handle a lot of game objects in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

A while ago I started practising in Unity. I made a football stadium that consists entirely of the 'normal cubes' (each seat consists of 2 cubes). Everything you see is made of cubes, no other assets have been used. In the picture it may still look reasonable, but when I walk into it, it is incredibly slow and jittery, of course because of the many (tens of thousands) of cubes that the view contains. I also experienced this in the normal scene, when I didn't even start the game.

Now I want to start over, and use assets instead of cubes, to make it all a bit nicer. The stadium will again have to contain tens of thousands of seats. My question: How do I avoid getting such a faltering image when I walk in it? Is there a trick to merge many seats into 1 grandstand, to reduce the number of objects, so that Unity/the computer can handle it better? I know the parent/child idea, but then you end up with tens of thousands of children, and thus tens of thousands of game objects. And then it is still faltering.

In the past I have only used cubes in Unity. This time I want to start in a way that will not allow me to run into this same problem again when the stadium is finished.

[image]

Comment: In general there is a good reason why this is often solved via simple sprites instead of 3d meshes ;)

Answer (score 2):

First, you have to reduce the number of meshes by combining them into larger simpler to handle meshes. There are a lot of tools, but you can do a lot with simple solutions like [Mesh Combiner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53835715/mesh-combiner-in-unity).

Also, make sure that you mark all non-moving objects as "static" so Unity can optimize better (this does not remove the need to combine the meshes as already mentioned).

[image]

Be careful so you don't add too many different materials.

If you have good 3D tools ([Blender](https://www.blender.org/) is free) you can use LOD (level of detail) groups. [Unity LOD Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ifNyVS2_6f8).

Finally, if you really want to have a living arena, and have some cash, why not add some animated meshes as in this asset [Mesh Animator](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/animation/mesh-animator-26009). I am sure there are other similar solutions, maybe even open source - anyone?

Comment: Thanks for your advice! :)